# Window Manager "Showing Desktop Mode"

Tags: window-manager

when I execute `wmctrl -m` I get the following output

```
spv@matrix:(~)$ wmctrl -m
Name: Compiz
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: OFF
```

Why is my "showing the desktop" mode OFF, and what difference does it make if it is ON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a mode where windows are hidden and just the desktop is shown - see the "_NET_SHOWING_DESKTOP" hint on the EWMH page at freedesktop.org:  http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#id2731380

so, something you would typically want off.